Blazor connect with delay in server side
I use blazor .net 9 web application my main page is static render for seo and indexing and one of my component is interactive server.
My problem is my signalr connect after 3 second
And i need signalr connect soon as possible
I use perrender mode for seo but customer found out and he didn't like it
How i handel it ?
I try to hide perrender and show component after render but google not index it,
For connection delay i use interactive server perrender but i have delay too

may i know how you are establishing the signalr connection?

I use Defualt Connection for it

i mean when you are stablishing the signalr connection OnInitializedAsync() or  OnAfterRenderAsync()? you could use browser developer tools to check the time it takes to establish the WebSocket connection to your SignalR endpoint.is it possible for you to first show the static content and show the interactive competent after the signalr connection is ready ?
